# 341kb "Icon" file in my Google Drive folders?

Tags: macos, finder, google-apps

I'm not sure whether to ask this here or on another Stack Exchange site.

See this screen capture:

[image]

This seems to be consistent on most if not all of my Google Drive folders as seen in Finder.

Also I don't know why the file name is vertically offset like that.

But basically, I don't want it there as it seems to be getting bundled in with .zip files that I try to create... How do I remove these and stop them from getting back into my folders?